# Initilizing a dictionary issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Instead of just initilizing

```
Screens (Dictionary<GameObject, string> Screens) values
```

this code creates a new gameObject screens with these associated values.

The problem is here:

```
Screens[new GameObject(cont.Key)] = cont.Value;
```

This is the result for screens : "Screens are created again with the associated values 
RightOuterPad=, LeftOuterPad=, LeftScreen=, RightOuterPad=,OPENPAD1-video-2 ,LeftOuterPad=OPENPAD1-video-1, LeftScreen=MAINBOARD1-video-2

```
Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();

content = ReadConfigFile(path);

Dictionary<GameObject, string> Screens = config.Screens;

List<string> ScreensNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var screen in Screens)
{
    ScreensNames.Add(screen.Key.name);
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cont in content)
{
    if (ScreensNames.Contains(cont.Key))
    {
        Debug.Log(Screens);
        Screens[new GameObject(cont.Key)]= cont.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @PeterSmith instead of initializing the dictionary values, it creates it again by associating the desired values

Comment: Okay, but what is the problem you are having?

Comment: This is the result for screens :   "Screens are created again with the associated values 
RightOuterPad= 
LeftOuterPad=
MiddleScreen=
RightScreen= 
LeftScreen=  
RightOuterPad=OPENPAD1-video-2 
LeftOuterPad=OPENPAD1-video-1
LeftScreen=MAINBOARD1-video-2 
MiddleScreen=MAINBOARD2-video-1 
RightScreen=MAINBOARD2-video-2

Comment: Can you please include the above comment in your question and say what you are expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is

```
using System.Linq;

...

var keyObjectReference = Screens.keys.FirstOrDefault(o => string.Equals(o.name, cont.Key));
config.Screens[keyObjectReference] = cont.Value;
```

this instead retrieves the first GameObject that has a matching name with `cont.Key` and uses that reference instead for accessing the correct entry in the `config.Screens` dictionary.